# How can I publish my own default html page when I get the error "Webpage not available" in my Android Studio App Webview?

Tags: html, android-studio, kotlin, webview

I have some Kotlin code on Android Studio that I use to find and show my own html pages on my Android app. If the html page exists the app works well and it pulls the html page from the assets folder and shows it via the webview capability.
If there is no html page with that name, then my app returns an error "Webpage not available     The webpage at      file:///android_asset/strainer.html could not be loaded because      net:ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"
Instead of this error I would like to show my own default html page. Please, does anyone know how I can do this?
My code is below:

// webview.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

```
            val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
            val q: String = text_view.getText().toString()
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + q + ".html")
       // myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + q + ".txt")
        myWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
```